# Return to labels and lambda expression in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I do not quite understand what is going on [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/returns.html#return-to-labels)

```
fun foo() {
    listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).forEach {
        if (it == 3) return // non-local return directly to the caller of foo()
        print(it)
    }
    println("this point is unreachable")
}

fun main() {
    foo()
}
```

The output is

> 12

So the integers `1` and `2`. That is because with `1` and `2` the expression `if (it == 3)` evaluates to `false`. But what is the `return` doing here? What is returned? And to where? Is there a way to write this more verbose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function `foo()` returns an implicit Unit, so when you call `return`, it simply returns from `foo()` immediately with the implicit Unit.

You could more verbosely write `return Unit`, and you could use a regular `for` loop. This is basically the same code that is being inlined by `forEach`.

```
fun foo(): Unit {
    for (it in listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) {
        if (it == 3) return Unit
        print(it)
    }
    println("this point is unreachable")
}
```

If instead you used `return@forEach`, with or without the implicit Unit, it would be returning from the lambda, which would be the same as using `continue` in a traditional for loop, since the `forEach` lambda is called repeatedly, once for each iteration of the loop.

If `foo()` returned something other than Unit, you would have to return that type to be able to do a non-local return:

```
fun foo(): Boolean {
    listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).forEach {
        if (it == 3) return false
        print(it)
    }
    println("this point is unreachable")
    return true
}
```

You can only do non-local returns from inline function lambdas that are not `crossinline`.